# Data Bag Items must contain a Hash or Mash error

Tags: chef-solo, databags

I am getting the following error when provisioning a chef node:

```
[2015-02-04T06:46:11-08:00] ERROR: Failed to load data bag item: "site1" "config"
==> default: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
==> default: ----------------------------------
==> default: Data Bag Items must contain a Hash or Mash!
```

I have verified that the data bag name **config.json** exists and there is an id within the data bag with the same name. Also the data bag path is set correctly in the Vagrant file.

config.json

```
{
"id": "config",
  "username": "user",
  "password": "pwd"
}
```

The JSON is valid.

**UPDATE.** 
Issue on Chef client 12.0.1 and 12.0.3. Does not occur when downgrading to 11.18.0.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known but unconfirmed bug. There is [a github issue](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/chef-vault/issues/20) open for the problem.

For what it's worth, the problem only seems to show up with Vagrant. As you discovered, the workaround is to use an 11.x release.

edit: I guess it doesn't only happen on vagrant!

Comment: No, it does not only happen with Vagrant. It happens on Amazon too.